# error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__'before [function]

Tags: c, pic, mplab

I'm running into a problem with PIC32 Compiler v2.02.

The compiler defines the type BOOL as follows:

```
typedef enum _BOOL { FALSE = 0, TRUE } BOOL;     // BOOL Type
```

I want to return one of the enumerated values in a fuction like so:

```
BOOL
MyFunction(void)
{
  if( PortAvailable() )
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

when I compile my code I get this error pretaining to "MyFunction":

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'MyFunction'
```

I'm upgrading my compiler from version 1.05 to version 2.02 where I created my own typedef of BOOL.  The code has worked just fine before attempting to use version 2.02.  (Yes I have removed my typedef of BOOL from the code).

Something I find very strange is if I delcare the function like so:

```
enum BOOL
MyFunction(void)
{
  if( PortAvailable() )
  {
    return TRUE;
  }
  else
  {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

the compiler does not give me the error above.  Am I using the enumerated BOOL correctly or does anyone know of a step that I am missing?

Comment: What comes immediately before the `MyFunction` definition in the code?

Comment: Another function but with a void return.**void
Initialize(void);**

  I forgot to mention that these errors are always in reference to the header file and not the main c file.

Comment: If the errors are occurring in the header file, then they wouldn't be occurring on the code you've shown here, would they?  Please post the actual code that is generating the error.

Comment: Does looking at the pre-processed output show that `BOOL` is a macro that resolves to something that causes the problem? (gcc and MSVC use the `-E` option to dump pre-processed output).

Comment: Are you sure you made the typedef or simply you have said "enum BOOL {...};"?

Comment: @jwodder let me see what I can do, this code is for my work so I need to clear what I can post.

Comment: @PaulStelian I'm not sure, the typedef is defined directly in the compiler code provided by Microchip and if I attempt to redefine the typdef the compiler notifies me that it was already defined.

Comment: You should then use normal booleans instead of that BOOL thing, if available.

Comment: (can you?) These booleans will probably behave better anyways. Built-in type `bool`, with values `true` and `false`

Comment: @PaulStelian I just tried what you suggested, using the Built-in type bool, and the compiler still gives me the same error.

Comment: That is a bit weird then. I'd like to see the full code, including where the "bool" type may be included.

Comment: @PaulStelian as I commented to jwodder a little earlier I have to clear what I post so I will attempt to update my question as quickly as possible, I appreciate the patience.

Comment: @R.Johnson Do let me know when it's updated (I don't get edit notifications on this site)

Comment: To get C99- standard `bool` support (if your compiler supports it) you may need to `#include <stdbool.h>`.  Also - make sure there's not a `#define BOOL _BOOL` somewhere in your codebase.

Comment: The *built-in* C99 boolean type is spelled `_Bool`.  This is part of the language.  The standard library provides `stdbool.h`, which defines `bool`, `true`, and `false` as a macros expanding to `_Bool`, `1`, and `0`, respectively.

Comment: The error message you are getting indicates that the compiler does not recognize the symbols preceding your function name as designating a data type.  There is no way we can be confident in any more specific diagnosis without a complete example with which we (or at least *you*) can reproduce it.  That doesn't need to be your proprietary code; it just needs to reproduce the error.

Comment: you might find this of interest: "note that symbols starting with double underscore, or underscore and a capital letter, are unconditionally reserved for the implementation. Yes, system headers use names with double underscores — they're part of the implementation and aren't allowed to pollute your namespace. You shouldn't pollute their namespace. For all practical purposes, and multiple counter-examples notwithstanding, treat names starting with underscore as reserved for the compiler."

Comment: DO NOT `typedef` enum definitions.

Comment: @user3629249 tell that to Microchip as the typedef enum is apart of their compiler code not mine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you again for taking the time to help me work through this problem.  I was able to determine that with the newer version of the Microchip C32 compiler, v2.02, I need to declare:

```
#include <plib.h>
```

which is the Pic32 standard library in the files that use the "new" BOOL typdef.  With the older version of the compiler it basically left the user to create their own typedeff of BOOL (which I did) but once I removed my typedeff from the code I did not add the appropriet header to declare the enumeration.

Rookie mistake on my part, but I hope this answer will help other people who are running accross a similar problem.